# Upload resize and center image

Tags: php, image, image-uploading

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_field']['tmp_name'])) {

    switch(strtolower($_FILES['image_field']['type']))
    {
        case 'image/jpeg':
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['image_field']['tmp_name']);
            break;
        case 'image/png':
            $image = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['image_field']['tmp_name']);
            break;
        case 'image/gif':
            $image = imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['image_field']['tmp_name']);
            break;
        default:
            exit('Unsupported type: '.$_FILES['image_field']['type']);
    }

    $max_width = 335;
    $max_height = 225;

    $old_width  = imagesx($image);
    $old_height = imagesy($image);
    $scale      = min($max_width/$old_width, $max_height/$old_height);
    $new_width  = ceil($scale*$old_width);
    $new_height = ceil($scale*$old_height);
    $render = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

    imagealphablending($render, false);
    imagesavealpha($render,true);
    $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($render, 255, 255, 255, 127);
    imagefilledrectangle($render, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $transparent);

    imagecopyresampled($render, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $old_width, $old_height);
}
```

because i want an image to upload, resize using max height or max width, and then center on a new black image created with the new sizes given.

Image it's resized, but i've got two problems

1) Image it's aligned to left of the resized image (335x225)
2) A black background it's on the right of the image

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Look image manipulation will really frustrate you and make you want to pull out you're hair if you use PHP's default functions without a wrapper.

I know this isn't much, but I prefer using a tiny wrapper class when working with PHP images and GD / GD2.

I have been using Tyler's Simple PHP framework for a number of years, and this is exactly why. Have a look at the following GD class:
https://github.com/tylerhall/simple-php-framework/blob/master/includes/class.gd.php

Example of it's usage is as follows:

```
// Fire up GD and resample the image
require("path/class.gd.php");

// This would be the file system path of the image /var/www/img/myimg.jpg
$GD = new GD($_FILES['image_field']['tmp_name']); 

$width = 335;
$heigh = 225;
$quality = 80; // % based as you know

// Scale it
$GD->cropCentered($width, $height);

// TO SAVE TO FILESYSTEM
$GD->saveAs($localFile, 'jpg', $quality);

// TO PRINT OUT DIRECTLY
$GD->output('jpg', $quality);
```

I haven't had the black bar issues in years :-D. Like I said this is but one example, I am sure many folks will have different ways of doing this. As long as it provides your desired output.

**NOTE** Scaling / Resizing images is quite costly, especially for large images. Try and only do this once, save the file, and rather to check if the saved file exists, then resizing it from the large images on the fly.